# Mysql 'Equal' (=) operator doesn't work when 'LIKE' operator does work

Tags: mysql, sql

**[MYSQL]**
Here are two queries that **should** bring out the same result.
but,

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE id = 12345;
```

Result: Nothing

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE id LIKE 12345;
```

Result: Correct Answer

Even 'id' is not a string, but int. How come this possible?

Comment: Provide a sample fiddle (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, 3-5 rows) which reproduces your issue. Now it looks like impossible.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you but please also add your full table definition.

Comment: @P.Salmon it only happens on this specific table, so I'm assuming it's because of MYSQL cache? I don't know. I just wanted to get some ideas.

Comment: Column id data type?

Comment: Which id values does your LIKE query return?

Comment: @jarlh id's datatype is bigint and values consist of multiple ints, varchar, bigint, date etc.. The funny thing is that if I do 'WHERE id = 33456', it gives the output. but then specific IDs don't work like in the example above when using LIKE works all the time.

Comment: Why do you store non-integer data in a bigint column? Give us some sample table data and the expected result - i.e. a [mcve]. (Use formatted text, not images or links.)

Comment: If you attempt to store anything other than and integer (or bigint or mediumint) type into bigint the insert will be rejected with a 1366 error if you are not getting an error then id is not bigint..if it is bigint I cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because of MySQL's implicit casting rules, your query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id LIKE 12345;
```

is being converted to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id LIKE '12345';
```

This is just the same as doing `WHERE id = '12345'`, which of course is a valid comparison and will behave as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if 'WHERE id = '12345' still doesn't give any result? What are the possibilties?

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE operator is a logical operator that tests whether a string contains a specified pattern or not.
Then Use this :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id LIKE '%'+'12345'+'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just the same problem, with intengers values but also with varchars, with a Drupal project...

In my case this happens after a Mariadb upgrade to the last version...
Really i made 2 upgrades, one to convert database to utf8mb4 and the Mariadb upgrade...

Just like you my query was

```
select * 
FROM taxonomy_vocabulary taxonomy_vocabulary
where machine_name = 'news_type'
```

With like works... With equal not...

At the end i made a simple change...  Edit the value of the record, and change it x other value... And return to write the original value...

And have other records affected... not all... but most that have the char "_"
(But also happened me on a integer value)...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).